# Limit front-end submitted posts by role

Tags: posts, limit

Right, I know this question has been asked, but, none have provided me with a workable solution, hoping someone can help.

I created a property listing site using the plugin Essential Real Estate. The plugin does offer a solution to limit posts using packages, the problem is that I need individual posts to expire in 6 months, the package solution expires the whole package.

So what I want to attempt is to place registered users on roles and them limit the number of posts each role can make.

I've tried plugins but none seem to work, I suspect this is because posting of the properties takes place via the front-end.

Really hope someone here can help, I'm rather desperate.

Comment: Are you looking for an out-of-the-box solution, or you want someone to do it for you, or you want to write some code? A very basic bit of code to do what you want should be possible somehow

Comment: @mozboz I'd prefer to try and write something myself, helps to learn more, but with respect to this problem I'm having I have no idea where to start.

In my head it should work something like this;

User in a role called "1-5 listings" tries to post a 6th listing. Once they try and submit a browser message pops up saying they can't.